# Vue JS. Layered calls not synchronised: Web Page -> VUEX-> API call

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have refactored my VUE JS code to have a dedicated API layer (Calls out to AWS Graphql services), it is called by the VUEX layer. It now has the following levels:

```
     Web Page -> Vuex  -> API
```

I want to retrieve data (this.getActivities) before referencing it (Point 7). I have cut down the code for simplicity:

```
 async created() {
    console.log("Point 1")
    await this.getActivities();

  },
 mounted() {
    console.log("Point 7")
    // reference the data set by this.getActivities()
  },


  methods: {
    
    async getActivities() {
      // from DB
      console.log("Point 2")
     this.$store.dispatch('getAllActivities')  // vuex call

    },


VUEX DATA STORE

 actions: {

     async getAllActivities ({ commit }) {
      console.log("point 3")

      const activities = await queries.getActivities()
 
      console.log("point 6")
      commit('setActivities', activities)

    },


API
  async getActivities () {

    await API.graphql({
        query: listActivities
      }).then((response) => {

         console.log("Point 4")

      })
      
      console.log("Point 5")


    return activitiesList
  },
```

Prints the following:
Point 1
Point 2
point 3
Point 7
Point 8
Point 4
Point 5
point 6

I presume I have misused the await/sync processes?

Thanks

Comment: You `await` only if you need to use the result in an immediately following statements. In your particular case there is absolutely no need for your `created` hook to be `async` - you simply dispatch your Vuex action and it takes care of the rest.

Comment: Thanks @IVOGELOV. I amended to   created() {
    console.log("Point 1")
    this.getActivities();

  },

Comment: I amended to:

created() {
    console.log("Point 1")
    this.getActivities();
  },

  Still prints in the same order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you need the list of activities in more than 1 component/route (otherwise why would you store this list in Vuex instead of the component itself ?!) you would normally do something like this:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <ActivityItem v-for="act in ACTIVITY_LIST" :key="act.id" :activity="act" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ActivityItem from './components/ActivityItem';
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex';
import { ACTIVITY_LIST, FETCH_ACTIVITIES } from './store/constants';

export default
{
  components:
  {
    ActivityItem,
  },
  computed:
  {
    ...mapGetters([ACTIVITY_LIST]),
  },
  created()
  {
    this[FECH_ACTIVITIES]();
  },
  methods:
  {
    ...mapActions([FETCH_ACTIVITIES])
  }
}
</script>
```

```js
// store/constants.js
export const ACTIVITY_LIST = 'ACTIVITY_LIST';
export const FETCH_ACTIVITIES = 'FETCH_ACTIVITIES';
export const SET_ACTIVITIES = 'SET_ACTIVITIES';
```

```js
// store/index.js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import { ACTIVITY_LIST, FETCH_ACTIVITIES, SET_ACTIVITIES } from './store/constants';
import myAPI from './api';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store(
  {
    strict: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
    state()
    {
      return {
        activities: []
      };
    },
    getters:
    {
      [ACTIVITY_LIST](state)
      {
        return state.activities;
      }
    },
    mutations:
    {
      [SET_ACTIVITIES](state, value)
      {
        state.activities = value || [];
      }
    },
    actions:
    {
      [FETCH_ACTIVITIES]({ commit })
      {
        return myAPI.getActivities().then(response =>
        {
          commit(SET_ACTIVITIES, response.data.activitiesList);
          return response.data.activitiesList; // optional
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks  @IVOGELOV  This is a great answer that goes beyond what I expected. It works and provides a great pattern to follow for myself and others. really appreciated.